# Problem sending data via Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth

I have an HM-11 BT module that I am configuring as a Master/Central and attempting to connecting to a SH-M08 BT slave module.

I can connect to the slave successfully but I cant send data.

I found this code on line. After configuring the HM-11, scanning and printing the found BT modules to serial, it reads commands from the serial port.

From the serial monitor I can send AT+CON[ADDR] and get back OK+CONNA and OK+CONN which indicates that connection was successful.

When I attempt to send anything via the serial connection it does not get received by the slave BT. I am able to used an app on my phone to send data to the slave BT.

This is the code.

```cpp
SoftwareSerial BTserial(2, 3); // RX, TX

#define baud 9600

void setup()  
{
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(baud);
  BTserial.begin(baud);
  
  at("AT"); // check if working, always returns OK
  at("AT+RENEW"); // select master = central  
  at("AT+ROLE1"); // select master = centra
  at("AT+RESET"); // actually more a restart than a reset .. needed after ROLE
  at("AT+SHOW1"); // include Bluetooth name in response
  at("AT+SCAN5"); // set discobery time to 5 seconds
  at("AT+IMME1"); // "work immediately", not sure what this does
  //at("AT+FILT0"); // show all BLE devices, not only HM ones
  delay(1000); // wait a bit, NECESSARY!!
  BTserial.print("AT+DISC?"); // here comes the magic
 while(!BTserial.find("OK+DISCS")) Serial.print("."); 
   Serial.println("OK+DISCS");
}

void at(char* cmd) {
  BTserial.write(cmd);
  Serial.print(cmd);
  while(!BTserial.find("OK")) Serial.print(".");
  while (BTserial.available()) Serial.write(BTserial.read());
  Serial.println(" .. OK");
}


void loop() // run over and over
{
  if (BTserial.available())
    Serial.write(BTserial.read());
  if (Serial.available())
    BTserial.write(Serial.read());   
}
```